# Zend default route not working

Tags: zend-framework, routes

I'm trying to add multi language functionality to an existing application.

My URL's look like this:

Without language: www.example.com/controller/action/params
With language: www.example.com/de/controller/action/params

If :lang is not specified ('de' in the example above) it should take the default language (set in the ini) or just use Zend_Translate default keys.

Both of the URL's above need to work.

My Problem now is the following: I'm able to activate get the first URL with the :lang working, but then the default one doesn't work. Why?

Somehow, the chaining of the default route and the language rout doesn't work properly.

My code is the same (for the chaining/routing stuff) like here: http://devzone.zend.com/1765/chaining-language-with-default-route/

I'm not using modules (actively, of course teh default stuff is enabled), maybe my default route (same as in the code) is just wrong? Althought it works, if i disable the language rout and chaining.

Comment: I have no answer to your question, but I see the same (with my recent project with some legacy code) thing -- language param as a (starting!) part of a url. Why would one use such a pattern? Why not just keep this locale param in session (if its not autodetected successfully)? Is this some SEO thing?

Comment: Can you add the code of your route to this question?